# Unity API PhotoCapture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to update the Unity PhotoCpature example to be usable within a function and not just running on start. However when I try and take the `Start()` code out and place it in another function `Snap()` the code no longer works and I am greeted with errors.

Errors Recieved

[image: Errors Recieved]

I do not understand how the why these errors continue to pop up when nothing has changed except for where the function is being called from.

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam;

public class TakePic : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    Texture2D targetTexture = null;

    void Start()
    {
        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        // Create a PhotoCapture object
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject)
        {
            photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
            CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
            cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
            cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

            // Activate the camera
            photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
            {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            });
        });
    }

    public void Snap()
    {
        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        // Create a PhotoCapture object
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject)
        {
            photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
            CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
            cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
            cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

            // Activate the camera
            photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
            {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            });
        });
    }

    void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {
        // Copy the raw image data into our target texture
        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

        // Create a gameobject that we can apply our texture to
        GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
        Renderer quadRenderer = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>() as Renderer;
        quadRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"));

        quad.transform.parent = this.transform;
        quad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);

        quadRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", targetTexture);

        // Deactivate our camera
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }


    void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        // Shutdown our photo capture resource
        Debug.Log("ShutDown!");
        photoCaptureObject.Dispose();

        photoCaptureObject = null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the code in the `Start` function. How and where are you calling the `Snap` function?

Comment: @Programmer I left Start and Snap to illustrate what I wanted to do. I am calling the Snap function Via an onClick component on an object in my scene.

When I take out whats in the Start function and only leave the Snap() I cant take one picture and then after that I receive the same errors as above stating that the Photomode is already started even tho I have shut it down in the last function.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Found a solution. I just needed a check in place to see if the object existed or not.
` if (photoCaptureObject == null)`