# Can Hololens take photo while live preview is on?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photo, live-streaming, hololens

I want to take photos with Hololens, I also want to showcase it live for audience. But photo capture not working while live preview is on. Is there a way or code that can achieve both. If not, how can I check whether Hololens has live preview mode on in C# code, so that I can turn it off for taking photo and turn it back on again? I'm using Unity3D and C#.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the limitation from MRC, you can check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mixed-reality-capture-for-developers#integrating-mrc-functionality-from-within-your-app) statements below:

*With the Windows 10 April 2018 Update, there is no longer a limitation around multiple apps accessing the MRC stream (however, the access to the photo/video camera still has limitations)*

To check whether the **PhotoCapture** is available to work, you should check whether the **PhotoCapture** object was created successfully and the result when the relative event was triggered. Please refer the code sample provided below:

[Locatable camera in Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable-camera-in-unity#photo-capture)

In-addition, any idea or feedback about HoloLens, you can submit via follow the link below:

[Give us feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/give-us-feedback)

Comment: ok,so both can't be done simultaneously. But is there a way to turn off **VideoMode (live preview)** and then turn back on after **PhotoCapture** is done? And sometimes **OnPhotoModeStarted** not successful and app crushed, what is the problem?

Comment: No, there is no such way to turn off live preview. You can check the REST API exposed by the device portal from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/device-portal-api-reference#mixed-reality-streaming). A recommend way is suggesting customer check the live preview feature and let the customer determine whether it should be turn off when your app failed to take photo. And for the app crashed issue, would you mind sharing more info about it? Does it happen regularly or just by chance. What's kind of operation cause the app crashed?

Comment: Couldn't debug or find the cause because it only happen sometimes. I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable-camera-in-unity) as photo capture function. After taking photos for multiple times, "OnPhotoModeStarted" **result not successful**, console log **Photo Mode has already been started** the app stuck there.

Comment: Did you mean that this issue could reproduced every-time when you taking photos for multiple times? If yes, would you mind sharing a minimum repro to help us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Not everytime, something it does, something doesn't, that's why I can't really debug and solve this problem. It rarely occurs, but when it does, can't uses camera anymore even after close and open app again. it seems like the camera is stuck in PhotoMode [WebCam.Mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/windowsholographic-webcamera.html). Similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985476/unity-api-photocapture), but only the first error (Photo mode has already been started).